# 2D Array of letter number combination indexes

Tags: java, matrix, indexing, spreadsheet

I am at a loss in creating a 2D matrix with a combination of letters and numbers as indexes.

Typically an array is accessed using `array[0][1]` or `array[3][2`]. How can I achieve looking up an array using letters like `array[A][1]` or `array[D][2]`? It should also use as many letters as the user desires. For instance, a user wants 10 rows and thus we have `array[J][1,2,etc.]`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the user a developer who will be writing code with references such as `a[A][10]`? If not, how will the user be entering these references?  Is the more basic question just how to define a collection key that contains letters and numbers? Is an array specifically required here?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the char into a index like:

```
char x = ...;
int index = x-'A';
array[index][3]
```

Comment: I do not understand. What is happening when you subtract an int with char 'A'? Am I wasting rows indexed with numbers when creating an array like this?

Comment: an char from 'A'  to 'J' substract an 'A' will be 0 to 9,that could be the index of this array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specifically index by A or D, as opposed to an index holding these values, that is usually done by making a "class constant".  There are also other ways, such as using enums, that I won't talk about here but look them up if they interest you.

In java a class constant is specified as follows.

```
public static int A = 0;    
public static int B = 1;
...
public static int Z = 25;
```

From here you can index exactly how you wrote in your question.

```
int value = array[A][1]; // which means array[0][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the interface of an associative array.  Is there any reason that a Map would not suit the problem?  A TreeMap would iterate alphabetically and preserve the ABC order of the indices.

```
Map<String, int[]> map = new TreeMap<String, int[]>();
map.put("A", new int[]{1,2,3,4,5});
```

Comment: This might not work because the matrix is determined by the user, meaning that Row A,B,C,etc. is not set. It is easy to do this by integers, but with letters it is a bit harder.